# Why are Fibonacci numbers on the Collatz conjecture function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, collatz-conjecture

$C(x) = \frac{1}{2}x$ if $x$ is even, $3x + 1$  if $x$ is odd

I will use $E$ to refer to an even number, and $O$ to refer to an odd number

1. $C(E)$ may be $E$ or may be $O$, as an even number divided by $2$ may be even or odd
2. $C(O)$ is always $E$, as an odd number multiplied by  $3$ and added $1$ is always even

with that, we could construct a map after applying the function $C(x)$ $n$ times

Let's say you start with some arbitrary odd number $O$.

0. $O$

If you apply the the function to $O$ it will be some even number $E$

1. $E$

If you apply the function to $E$ you will have 2 possible values, $E$ and $O$

2. $(E, O)$

Now $E$ can turn intro $E$ or $O$, and $O$ turn intro $E$

3. $(E, O, E)$

If you continue the process and see how many terms you get on each iteration, what you get is:
$1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21...$

Why did it happen? Are those really the Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: The fibonacci numbers also solve a special counting problem which seems to pop up here.

Comment: When you say "If you apply the function to $E$ you will have $2$ possible values, $E$ and $O$", that not how I see it, as halving any particular $E$ will either give you an $E$ or give you an $O$, but not both.

Comment: You can think about this as the original source for Fibonacci numbers (breeding rabbits), if you think about $O$ as fresh rabbits, and $E$ as mating rabbits: fresh rabbits become mating ($O \to E$), and mating keep mating and also born a new fresh pair ($E \to EO$).

Comment: @Henry it's not mapping one particular path, it's mapping all possible paths after applying the function n times, so I put both there

Comment: @mihaild Didn't know about this, can you post as an answer?

Comment: @WagnerMartins but some of these paths are not possible.  I do not see Fibonacci numbers appearing in https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Collatz-graph-20-iterations.svg which might suggest the reverse sequence [OEIS A005186](https://oeis.org/A005186)

Comment: @Henry they are different graphs, the one from the image you sent is an inverse Collatz map, where you start with 1 and apply the inverse function, the one from my post is a graph starting from an arbitrary number and showing the possible paths after the initial seed

Comment: @WagnerMartins There is only one possible forward path from any particular seed.  If you start at $13$ you will go to $40$ and then to $20$ and then to $10$; going from $20$ to $61$ is not an option.

Comment: @Henry the path of 13 is one of the paths you can follow on the graph, O (13) -> E (40) -> E (20)-> E (10) -> O  (5) -> E (16) -> E (8) -> E -> E (4) -> E (2) -> O (1) -> E (4) -> E (2) -> O (1) -> E (4) -> E (2) -> O (1)...

Comment: @Henry for example, O -> E -> E ... is a valid path, but O -> E -> O -> O ... is not, because you can't go from an odd number to other odd number on any seed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of definitions of Fibonacci numbers ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Europe) claims it was the original one used by Fibonacci) is as follow: imagine that we have a pair of newborn rabbits. Newborn rabbits take one month to grow up. Grown up pair of rabbits every month give birth to a new pair of rabbits. Then $n$-th Fibonacci number is number of rabbits we have in $n$-th month: we have $F_{n - 1}$ grown up rabbits and $F_{n - 2}$ newborn for a total of $F_{n - 1} + F_{n - 2} = F_n$ rabbits, next month we will have $F_{n - 1} + F_{n - 2} = F_n$ grown up ($F_{n - 1}$ we already had plus $F_{n - 2}$ newly grown) and $F_{n - 1}$ newborn.

This is exactly the same process you use if you consider $O$ as a newborn rabbit, and $E$ as a grown up: on each step, each newborn rabbit grows up, while already grown up remain and also give birth to newborn.

Comment: Wikipedia's claim isn't quite right.  In Fibonacci's original statement of the problem, the initial pair were not *newborn*, but *already reproductive*.

Comment: If you look in the right margin of [the page of *Liber abaci*](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Liber_abbaci_magliab_f124r.jpg) reproduced in the Wikipedia article, you will see *thirteen* successive numbers of the Fibonacci sequence. The first of these (viz. $1$) is the number of pairs *at the start of the first month*, and the $\ i^\text{th}$ in the sequence, for $\ i=2,3,\dots,13\ $, is the number of pairs at the *end* of the $\ (i-1)^\text{th}$ month, thus making $377$ the number of pairs at the end of a year.